# Eventfd role in Linux

Tags: linux

I read that eventfd is efficient as kernel will informs user process about event on file description.  I saw its example at

http://graphics.sci.ubu.ac.th/api/man-html/htmlman2/eventfd.2.html

1. I saw two argument :
   a. one is unsigned int initval, which is kernel counter. how can i use this?
   b. int flags, what is its role?
2. what is role and where can i use it?

I saw example but its uses unable to understand.

Why is it required?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [**detailed man page of eventfd**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) with special attention to the following :

- [**eventfd() example**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html#EXAMPLE) demonstrating IPC(Inter Process Communication) between a parent-child process pair.
- **`initval` is the "built-in" counter in eventfd**.
  Checkout the behaviour of `read(), write(), poll(), select()` to see how the value of the counter affects their behavior on an eventfd.
- **`flags` parameter decides the semantics of the eventfd**.
  Depending upon your kernel version, the following flags are available to choose from `EFD_CLOEXEC`, `EFD_NONBLOCK` and `EFD_SEMAPHORE`.